# Angular Material: 'mat-dialog-content' is not a known element

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-components

*Before marking this question as "duplicate", kindly hear me out since I'm stuck for hours with this problem. I've gone through the existing questions but could not find any solution.*

I'm learning Angular and have started with Angular 9+ and Angular Material. I'm trying to implement a simple dialog of Angular Material by reading the documentation from the [official page](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview).

My code closely follows the example code but I'm at a loss on why I'm still getting this error messages:

```
'mat-dialog-content' is not a known element.
'mat-dialog-actions' is not a known element.
```

The dialog does show up but it looks as if no Angular Material components / directives are being rendered at all in the dialog template html. Even if I use `<button mat-button>Button</button>`, it would be rendered as a normal button and not an Angular Material button. Everything else which is not in the dialog template works perfectly fine. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here, but if anyone could point me out my mistake, that'd be great!

`app.module.ts`: (I'm importing the `MatDialogModule`)

```
...
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        ...
    ],
    imports: [
        ...
        MatDialogModule
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

`mycomponent.ts`:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog, MatDialogModule, MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialogConfig } from '@angular/material/dialog';
...

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my',
  templateUrl: './my.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my.component.css']
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(public dataDialogHandler: MatDialog) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {}

    public openDataDialog(): void {

        const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();

        dialogConfig.data = {};

        this.dataDialogHandler.open(DataDialogComponent, dialogConfig);
    }
}

@Component({
    selector: 'data-dialog',
    templateUrl: './data-dialog.html'
})
export class DataDialogComponent {

    constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: DialogData) {}
}

export interface DialogData {}
```

`data-dialog.html`:

```
<h2 mat-dialog-title>some title</h2>
<mat-dialog-content>
    <p>dialog works</p>
</mat-dialog-content>
<mat-dialog-actions align="end">
    <button mat-button mat-dialog-close>Close</button>
</mat-dialog-actions>
```

and finally, in `my.component.html`:

```
<button mat-button (click)="openDataDialog()">View Dialog</button>
```

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance!

```
@angular/core 9.0.7
@angular/cdk 9.1.3
@angular/material 9.1.3
typescript 3.7.5
```

Answer (score 18):

Change the `mat-dialog-content` and `mat-dialog-actions` to attributes.
i.e:

```html
<div mat-dialog-content>
    <p>dialog works</p>
</div>
<div mat-dialog-actions align="end">
    <button mat-button mat-dialog-close>Close</button>
</div>
```

Comment: This solved my problem working with Angular 11

Comment: I was migrating from angular & material 7 to 11 . Ng update should have taken care this but not.  I had to make changes manually.

Comment: This was super frustrating to figure out.  Thank you so much.

Comment: I wonder why its working after changing a tag into property.

Comment: Strange, I was already on version 12 and it worked.
On migration to version 13 began to complain.

Comment: Cause: Updating the component has changed the name of your module. It was with the wrong name in the shared.module, it caused an error in the compilation.
This error was not accused, it was hidden, showing the error treated in this post.

See if you're not having the same problem and looking for the wrong cause.

Answer (score 11):

Please add **DataDialogComponent** in the declarations array, and in entryComponents array of app.module.ts

```
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
       DataDialogComponent //I think you have missed this declaration
    ],
    imports: [
        ...
        MatDialogModule
    ],
    providers: [],
   entryComponents: [DataDialogComponent]
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: `MyComponent` is already added to the declarations along with `AppComponent`. But that does not fix the issue.

Comment: How about DataDialogComponent? Is that added in the declarations array as well?

Comment: @SajibAcharya, please accept the answer if this helped you.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solved it by moving the dialog component and the container components into different files. At the moment you've got this setup where both the dialog and the container component are declared in the same file:

```
# my.component.ts

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my',
  templateUrl: './my.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my.component.css']
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(public dataDialogHandler: MatDialog) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {}

    public openDataDialog(): void {

        const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();

        dialogConfig.data = {};

        this.dataDialogHandler.open(DataDialogComponent, dialogConfig);
    }
}

@Component({
    selector: 'data-dialog',
    templateUrl: './data-dialog.html'
})
export class DataDialogComponent {

    constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: DialogData) {}
}

export interface DialogData {}
```

#### Split the components into separate files

I would suggest creating an entirely new dialog component that handles its own dependencies so that you end up with this:

```
# my.component.ts

import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import{ MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';

# Make sure you import your newly created component
import{ MyDataDialog } from 'src/app/wherever-youve-put-it/my-data-dialog.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my',
  templateUrl: './my.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my.component.css']
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(public dataDialogHandler: MatDialog) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {}

    public openDataDialog(): void {

        const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();

        dialogConfig.data = {};

        this.dataDialogHandler.open(MyDataDialogComponent, dialogConfig);
    }
}
```

Then use `ng generate component my-data-dialog` to create a new component to be your dialog. You can then copy across dependencies and code into (you'll be less likely to get references etc. wrong if you use the CLI to generate it and copy rather than just copy into a new handcrafted component)

```
# my-data-dialog.component.ts

import { Component, OnInit, Inject} from '@angular/core';
import{ MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material/dialog';

@Component({
    selector: 'data-dialog',
    templateUrl: './data-dialog.html'
})
export class DataDialogComponent {

    constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: DialogData) {}
}

export interface DialogData {}
```

Comment: So I was trying a few ways regarding this. The way I found that it works 100% of the time is by adding the Dialog Component in the declarations of 1app.module` and also importing `MatDialogModule` and (optionally) `MatButtonModule` to `app.module`'s imports. Weird that this works for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got a solution for my problem!

Needed to answer here because I think it's the same thing. It'll help a lot of people for sure!

So, there are two problems: The firt is that you aren't exporting 'MyComponent'.

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        ...
    ],
    imports: [
        ...
        MatDialogModule
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    exports: [ AppComponent,         #add this code
              MyComponent ],
})
```

It seems that angular can't bind your imports in a class that isn't exported. Well that solved the problem in HTML file.
Now the second one: for the test, after you add your component in your "module.ts", you need to add the MatDialogModule in "spec.ts" too:

```
beforeEach(async() => {
await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [ CommonModule,
    ...,
    MatDialogModule],
```

After these changes it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the current Material docs:

```
<h2 mat-dialog-title>Delete all elements?</h2>
```

This will delete all elements that are currently on this page and cannot be undone.

Cancel

<button mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="true">Delete

and [here](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview)

Do not work for Angular 12. The solution above by Danilo Mz worked for me.

Ie: "
Change the mat-dialog-content and mat-dialog-actions to attributes"

Answer (score -1):

You are missing the `entryComponents` declaration.

Also add interface for DialogData

```
export interface DialogData {
 example: string;
}
```

Live: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q4mwkt

[MatDialog - Medium Post](https://medium.com/@ppm1988/angular-material-dialog-matdialog-9a001cb6b99a?postPublishedType=repub)

Comment: I tried this, by adding `DataDialogComponents` to `entryComponents`. But this still does not solve the issue.

Comment: It works well for me with the exact code that you have shared - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q4mwkt

Comment: Make sure you have compatible versions of core, common, compiler, cdk, material and animations in package.json

Comment: Do spelling check as well. I see that you have mentioned `DataDialogComponents` in the comments whereas in the question it is `DataDialogComponent` in singular form.

Comment: Okay I looked into your stackbliz code and it doesn't work there. If you open the dialog, look how you've used mat-button but the dialog only shows a normal html button.

Comment: I thought your issue was mat-dialog not showing up. You have to import every material module if you want to make use of them. Now I have updated the stackblitz by importing the mat-button module as well.

Comment: I only copy pasted your code and I did not try to do anything extra to make it work.