# 'mat-dialog-actions' is not a known element in angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I know this question is duplicate ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60789734/angular-material-mat-dialog-content-is-not-a-known-element)). but I have problem.
I have added the `MatDialogModule` in the import section of AppModule.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Content of my dialog :

```
<h2 mat-dialog-title>Install Angular</h2>
<mat-dialog-content class="mat-typography">
    <h3>Develop across all platforms</h3>
</mat-dialog-content>
<mat-dialog-actions align="end">
    <button mat-button mat-dialog-close>Cancel</button>
    <button mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="true" cdkFocusInitial>Install</button>
</mat-dialog-actions>
```

When I want to open dialog :

```
  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) {}

  openDialog() {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(CourseAcitonComponent);

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log(`Dialog result: ${result}`);
    });
  }
```

I get the following Error :

1-

```
If 'mat-dialog-content' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
```

2-

```
Can't bind to 'mat-dialog-close' since it isn't a known property of 'button'.
<button mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="true" cdkFocusInitial>Install</button>
```

Comment: Wherever you are calling openDialog method from, is it within appModule context?

Comment: @alou - Thanks . Yes .It is within appModule context

Answer (score 3):

Just like the example here:
https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview#dialog-data

```
@Component({
  selector: 'dialog-data-example-dialog',
  templateUrl: 'dialog-data-example-dialog.html',
})
export class DialogDataExampleDialog {
  constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: DialogData) {}
}
```

You need to import and add `DialogDataExampleDialog` in `app.module.ts`

```
declarations: [
  AppComponent,
  // ...
  DialogDataExampleDialog // Import and add this line
],
```

Answer (score -1):

mat-dialog-content is a directive, not a component and so should be used as a directive:

```
<div mat-dialog-content>
   Mycontent
</div>
```

Angular generates dynamic content inside the dialog element. So we have to add the dialog box class at declarations and entryComponents in the @NgModule in our module.ts file. My app.module.ts

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
   MatDialogModule
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    MatDialogModule
  ],
})
```

I hope now you can also resolve your problem.